# get most frequently called lambda functions in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In AWS Lambda if I view a Lambda functions' Monitoring tab I can see an Invocations graph that shows me the number of calls to the Lambda function over time.
Is there something in AWS that can tell me which Lambda functions are the most frequently called out of all my Lambda functions? I don't want to have to look at each Invocations graph individually to figure it out.

Comment: I don't know about doing this with AWS itself but third parties like Epsagon and iopipe can do this (and more).

Comment: @macbutch it's only a one-off question at this point (in that I don't expect any real changes in invocation frequency) so I was hoping for something in AWS.

Comment: Fair enough. I can't think of an easy way to do it (doesn't mean you can't though) unless you could put invocation counts on a Cloudwatch dashboard or something like that so you can compare them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CloudWatch to see all your Lambda invocations.
Just switch to [Lambda](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?#cw:dashboard=Lambda) view and check **Invocations Sum** view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realise the CloudWatch: Overview dropdown gave per-service statistics.

Comment: And a note to anyone using this, CloudWatch has a limit of 100 resources so it will only display 100 Lambdas (not necessarily the 100 most frequently called either).

Comment: In the 2023 AWS console, it is: Cloudwatch > Dashboards > Automatic dashboards > Lambda